# chrome-extension://${id}/nhc.htm#url=${url}

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with running the Google plugin IE-TAB on the webpage.

```html
<a href="chrome-extension://`{ID}`/nhc.htm#url=`{URL}`">testClick</a>
```

Jump to blank page when clicking on a tag.
Is there any other way to open the Google Chrome plugin in html or js?

Comment: Only those pages that the extension exposes via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Answer (score 1):

`chrome-extension:` URL schema is privileged (like `chrome:` for Chrome internal pages, for example).

A web page context cannot initiate navigation to those pages. It will be intercepted and redirected to `about:blank`.

As wOxxOm mentions in a comment, it's possible for the extension to whitelist some of its URLs as usable in web contexts through `web_accessible_resources`.

Since you're asking about an existing 3rd party extension IE Tab, bad news for you:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/extapi_wp.js",
    "js/ietabapi_wp.js",
    "redir.htm"
],
```

`/nhc.htm` is not on the list, so you can't (short of making your own version of IE Tab) do that.

Comment: I added the nhc.htm configuration to web_accessible_resources, but still can't jump to the specified link, or jump to about:blank